# If the transformation of matrix $A$ is $R^n\longrightarrow R^n$, does that imply a square matrix? Likewise, if it's not onto, then is it one-to-one?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The question asks

> If $TA: R^n\longrightarrow R^n$ is not an onto linear transformation then $A$ is not invertible.

I'm supposed to prove it if it's true, and use a counterexample if it's false. I want to use the Invertible Matrix Theorem, but I'm not sure if the line $R^n\Rightarrow R^n$ implies that the matrix is $n \times n$ or square.

Comment: If it is not onto then it not one-to-one too. Then this implies the kernel of TA is not {0}. i.e. there exists a non zero vector in R^n that get sends to 0 under TA. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I never learned anything about kernels yet. My understanding of not being onto is that for every output, there is not at least one input. However, there can still be an output for every input.

Answer (score 1):

$\text{dim} \;R^n = n < \infty$

by the rank–nullity theorem

$rk(A)  = n - \text{dim}(\text{ker}(A))$

$\text{ker}(A) \neq \{0\}$ because it is not onto (so it's not injective either) therefore $\text{dim}(\text{ker}(A))>0$

so $rk(A) < n \implies $ there exists atleat two column vectors of $A$ that are linearly dependant and that implies $\text{det} A = 0$

conclusion : $A$ is not invertible

Comment: I haven't learned rank or kernels, I'm not sure what they mean...our text hasn't really discussed it like that so far.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are working with finite dimensional vector space, the rank nullity theorem implies that an endomorphism of a vector space $V$ is surjective if and only if it is injective. 
This means in your case that $TA$ is not injective, then the kernel of the linear transformation is not trivial. Let $m$ the dimension of $\ker TA$, then $m>0$ and it is equal to $n-rk A$. Then the rank of $A$ is not maximal, that is $n$, then $A$ is not invertibile, because of the following result $\det A\neq 0 \iff rk A=n$.

Comment: We haven't gone over that theorem, so far the text hasn't really discussed rank at all. I'm sort of confused. Also, nothing about kernels have been explained so far.